# Blocking IP's behind varnish

Tags: varnish

I'm using varnish to speed up my website, but I've noticed because it is technically a reverse proxy, all IP's show as 127.0.0.1 - I've fixed this by using 
`HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`, but that's only fixing php programs, such as my forums. I've read through similar questions here where people are having issues trying to do "deny from" in htaccess, and it's not working due to varnish.

Many solutions after my research show that blocking IP's at the varnish level is the way to go, and unfortunately that's not working either. I've tried apache's mod_rpaf to attempt blocking IP's at the htaccess level, but that didn't do anything either.

Here is my varnish code in an attempt to block an example IP:

```
sub vcl_recv {
       if (client.ip ~ blacklist) {
           return (synth(403));
       }
}
```

And now the acl blacklist

```
acl blacklist {
"1.1.1.1";
}
```

With this setup, 1.1.1.1 is still able to access the website, and is not brought to my 403 page.
To clarify, I'm using varnish 4, so the "error 403" is not compatible anymore, so you need to use `return`.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Has anybody else been in the same situation where they need to block IP's at the varnish level? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, [here](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/reference/vcl.html#access-control-list-acl) is the ACL documentation for Varnish 4.0.

This shouldn't matter, but have you tried explicitly stating the netmask?

```
acl blacklist {
    "1.1.1.1"/32;
}
```

Is Varnish at the front-most layer of your stack?  If you look at the requests with `varnishlog`, are the IPs you see what you expect?